# How to get comment in XML tag from response use Scrapy?

Tags: python, xml, scrapy

I have response from server like code below.
I want to get the link in the CDATA section in between the `<lyric></lyric>` tags.

```
<lyric><![CDATA[https://lrc-nct.nixcdn.com/2018/02/21/f/b/1/1/1519207822262.lrc]]></lyric>
<bgimage><![CDATA[https://avatar-nct.nixcdn.com/singer/avatar/2018/02/25/e/b/b/b/1519558155015_600.jpg]]></bgimage>
<avatar><![CDATA[https://avatar-nct.nixcdn.com/song/2018/02/26/f/8/3/d/1519640161758.jpg]]></avatar>
<coverimage><![CDATA[https://avatar-nct.nixcdn.com/song/2018/02/26/f/8/3/d/1519640161758_500.jpg]]></coverimage>
<newtab><![CDATA[https://www.nhaccuatui.com/nghe-si-hang-bingboong.html]]></newtab>
```

Comment: Could you post a link to the website you're crawling? CDATA usage seems to be unusual here.

Comment: Format link like : https://www.nhaccuatui.com/flash/xml?html5=true&key1=59f0ae8a89cea4a0eb2c3b7e40208f26

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `lxml` strips away cdata and unfortunately `parsel.Selector` scrapy is using does not expose that option.

So you need to create lxml tree manually and then recreate your Selector:

```
$ scrapy shell "https://www.nhaccuatui.com/flash/xml?html5=true&key1=59f0ae8a89cea4a0eb2c3b7e40208f26"
from lxml.etree import XMLParser
from parsel import Selector

# lets fix selector
parser = XMLParser(strip_cdata=False)
root = etree.fromstring(response.body, parser=parser, base_url=response.url)
selector = Selector(root=root)

# now finding CDATA values
selector.xpath('//lyric/text()').extract()
[OUT]: ['https://lrc-nct.nixcdn.com/2018/02/07/a/a/e/f/1517979335534.lrc']
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to get the link('https://lrc-nct.nixcdn.com/2018/02/21/f/b/1/1/1519207822262.lrc')?
you can convert the xml content to string and use regular expression to extract the link.

```
re= re.findall('<lyric><!\[CDATA\[(.*)\]\]></lyric>',XMLstring)
```

Comment: I use Scrapy to crawl data bro.

Comment: @NhatNgo You can still include regex in your scrapy spider and than extract data from the extracted by regex part.